# Using real parameter to determine counter sizes

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I am trying to make my debounce code more modular by passing in parameters that are the frequency and the desired bounce time to eliminate button/switch bounce. This is how I approached it:

```
module debounceCounter 
#(
    parameter CLOCK_FREQUENCY_Hz = 50_000_000,
    parameter BOUNCE_TIME_s     = 0.003
)
(
    input wire sysClk, reset,
    input wire i_async,
    output reg o_sync  
);
    /* include tasks/functions */
    `include "clog2.v"

    /* constants */
    parameter [(clog2(BOUNCE_TIME_s * CLOCK_FREQUENCY_Hz + 0.5) - 1) : 0] 
        MAX_COUNT = BOUNCE_TIME_s * CLOCK_FREQUENCY_Hz;
```

Synthesis using Xilinx ISE 14.7 Throws this error:

```
Xst:850 - "../../rtl/verilog/debounceCounter.v" line0: Unsupported real 
    constant
```

How can I get around this issue so that I can determine the counter size and max count value based on parameters being passed in from code above this module in the heirarchy? A majority of my code has sizes of variables and such determined by frequency generics, so not being able to use methods like VHDL has proven to create problems in my designs.

Comment: Can you try after removing the function `clog2` from synthesis. I believe that XST takes functions as `real` types and `real` are not supported for synthesis for XST.

Comment: Not necessarily the best option (but Im not sure I know Xilinx synthesis tools well enough to deal with the `real` parameters you are using) is to change units to avoid real values entirely (eg, change `BOUNCE_TIME_s = 0.003` to `BOUNCE_TIME_ms = 3` and just divide out the 1000 to correct the units later)

Comment: @sharvil111 I am using a clog2 function Xilinx recommends in one of their AR's which is synthesizing fine for other modules. @Unn I removed all the reals and changed the units, but the tool is now complaining about the division, probably where I am calculating the max value: `Xst:867 - "../../verilog/debounceCounter.v" line0: Operator / is only supported when the second operand is a power of 2`

Comment: If it is xilinx recommended API, then you are fine. As @Unn suggested, you might have any other `real` operation going on. Now as [this PDF]( https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/xst_v6s6.pdf) suggests, you might have to divide it by power of 2 only. Somehow you need to get rid of `real` values getting generated in this code.

Comment: These suggestions worked and I got it synthesizing! I was mixing a data type when calling my clog2() function, e.g. integer*std_logic_vector(not sure the proper term in verilog). Once I fixed this and removed the real operations, synthesis was okay with the /1000. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine on Vivado 2016.3 (the oldest I have available). I think the problem is that 2014.7 is too old to support this. You didn't show the contents of the `include, but I'm assuming its the one from [AR# 44586](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/44586.html). If so, it should take and return integers and it will truncate the real floating point values for you. Floating point arithmetic is fine to use in Verilog/SystemVerilog testbenches and parameters.

> How can I get around this issue so that I can determine the counter
>   size and max count value based on parameters being passed in from code
>   above this module in the heirarchy?

- Update to a recent version. 2017.1 or 2017.3 are working good for me. I tested the following on 2016.3 and it also worked fine.
- Try using SystemVerilog (.sv) which supports the $clog2() system function natively without the `include. Not sure when .sv started working, but probably needs 2015+.
- Verify that your version of clog2 in the clog2.v header matches the following

***NOTE: There is another pretty serious bug in the code you posted.***
When you want to get the MSB required to hold a constant expression "x" the pattern should be `$clog2((x)+1)-1`. You have only added 0.5 instead of 1. This causes there to not be enough bits whenever the result of the floating point expression "x" falls between 2^n and (2^n + 0.5). For example, what you have erronously computes the constant as **17'h0** instead of **18'h4_0000** for the the frequency 87381333 but it still appears to work for your example at 50Mhz. Murphy's law says you will accidentally fall into this narrow bad range at the worst possible time, but never during testing :).

For reference, this is what I tested, with the `include expanded inline:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module debounceCounter 
#(
    //parameter CLOCK_FREQUENCY_Hz = 50_000_000,
    parameter CLOCK_FREQUENCY_Hz = 87381333, // whoops
    parameter BOUNCE_TIME_s     = 0.003
)
(
    input wire sysClk, reset,
    input wire i_async,
    output reg o_sync  
);
    /* include tasks/functions */
    //`include "clog2.v"
    function integer clog2;
        input integer value;
        begin
            value = value-1;
            for (clog2=0; value>0; clog2=clog2+1)
                value = value>>1;
        end
    endfunction

    /* constants */
    //parameter [(clog2(BOUNCE_TIME_s * CLOCK_FREQUENCY_Hz + 0.5) - 1) : 0] // <- BUG!!! 0.5 should 1
    parameter [(clog2(BOUNCE_TIME_s * CLOCK_FREQUENCY_Hz + 1) - 1) : 0]
    MAX_COUNT = BOUNCE_TIME_s * CLOCK_FREQUENCY_Hz;

    initial
        $display("MAX_COUNT %d", MAX_COUNT);

 endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Type Real is not synthesizable.  Draw/Create your design before you translate into/write HDL and you will realize this. Ask yourself, "What does a real synthesize to in gates?"

For those tools (e.g. Synplify) that do "support" Type Real, it is just a vendor interpretation, and as such is impossible to "support" since it is not defined as part of any HDL standard.  The implication: If you had a simulator that interprets Type Real one way, and your synthesizer (likely) interprets it another way, you will get sim/syn mismatches.  You may get away with them, depending on what you are trying to accomplish, but, it would still be considered poor design practice.

Behavioral code, for modeling and use in testbenches, as stated above, a different story as it is not synthesized.

Comment: I understand it is not synthesizable. I am used to designing modular VHDL code, where real is supported for instantiating constants... with the requirement, I believe, that you must take the result and type-cast it to something synthesizable. However, in this implementation, I used the accepted answer to get what I needed to synthesize properly. All I was doing was making my code reusable with this support during synthesis. As you can see with the parameter, this is not something that is being done with logic...

Comment: To phrase my comment differently. I changed the units of my compilation time calculation to not be real (I used ms*MHz) and this also removed any issues as the tools do not support calculations greater than the size of an integer, at least ISE 14.7 doesn't. Maybe I didn't state this obviously enough in my post, but the parameter uses a clog2 function that returns an integer for the length calculation so that this is indeed a "bus" of wires.